# Equality operator and properties in prototype chain from different frames

Tags: javascript, dom

When comparing functions from the prototype of a type across frames (same origin), I get the strangest behavior:

```
>>> window.frames[0].HTMLDocument.prototype.open === HTMLDocument.prototype.open
false
```

It's exactly the same behavior when using the less-strict `==`.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: For reference: This relates to what is defined in the ES6 spec as "realms": http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-code-realms (also related: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects).

Answer (score 3):

Different frames mean different global objects. You will have two distinct objects that do the same. Similarly, `window.Object !== frames[0].Object`. This is also why you [shouldn't use `instanceof Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) when possibly dealing with multiple environments.

Notice that this has nothing to do with the [equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1048572) you were using, they work the same on objects and compare them by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Each browsing context has a separate JavaScript environment.

According to the [W3C's HTML5 spec on Web APIs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/webappapis.html#script-settings-for-browsing-contexts):

> Whenever a new `Window` object is created, it must also create a script settings object...
>
> When the script settings object is created, for each language supported by the user agent, **create an appropriate execution environment as defined by the relevant specification.**

This requires that every browsing context (i.e., every page in a tab, frame, etc.) have a separate realization of the JavaScript environment. This means that every single page must have a different object for each page (thereby failing a `==` check) for environmental objects, constructors, and other functions.